# Swift: using .contains on multidimensional array

Tags: arrays, swift, contains

In swift, I cannot figure out how to check if a multi-dimensional array contains a child array.

```
var a: [[Int]] = []
a.append([1,2])
a.append([2,2])
a.append([3,2]) #=> [[1,2], [2,2], [3,2]]

a.contains([1,2]) #=> Contextual type '@noescape ([Int]) throws -> Bool' cannot be used with array literal.
```

I've tried all kinds of combinations and .indexOf and can't get anything to work.

What am I missing?

Comment: In your case: `a.contains { $0 == [1,2] }`. indexOf has also a predicate-based variant: `a.indexOf { $0 == [1,2] }`.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with the predicate form of contains:

```
a.contains {$0 == [1,2]}
```